# Is this elementary probability solution incorrect?

Tags: probability

I am tutoring some students in an elementary statistics class, and one of their homework questions is the following:

> The random variable $X$, representing the number of items sold in a week, has the following probability distribution:
>
> $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
>  x & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
> P(X=x) & 0.10 & 0.20 & 0.40 & 0.15 & 0.05 & 0.05 & 0.05 \\ \hline
> \end{array}$$
>
> By the fourth day of a particular week, $3$ items have already sold. What is the probability that there will be less than a total of $5$ items sold during that week?

The solution given is $0.67$, as it claims that we only need to compute $P(X<5\mid X\geq 3)$. However, the question says "by the fourth day...". Doesn't giving that particular day of the week affect the probability, so it can't be as simple as computing the above conditional probability?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would agree with you that the problem is poorly specified.  Suppose that, instead of the fourth day, they had said "with $30$ seconds left to go in the week..." or something else?  Clearly the answer depends on this.  Of course there are some natural sounding assumptions one could make to deal with this.

Comment: Actually, can you explain how they got $P(X<5 | X \geq 3) = 0.67$ ? I don’t get it.

Comment: @AdamRubinson In general, $P(A\mid B)=P(A\text{ and } B)/P(B)$. So, $P(X<5\mid X\geq 3) = P(X<5 \text{ and } X\geq 3)/P(X\geq 3)$. The top is just when $X=3$ or $4$ and the bottom is when $X=3$, $4$, $5$, or $6$. Since the probabilities are disjoint, its just $(P(X=3)+P(X=4))/(P(X=3)+P(X=4)+P(X=5)+P(X=6))$.